# Issues with validating case statement in SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I've created a query that pulls all data from one Data Extension (DE A) and moves it to another (DE B), renaming the fields as it goes. Now I'm adding a CASE statement to put a True/False value into a field called Investment_Insights_Market_Commentary__c that exists in DE B but not in DE A.

I get the error when trying to save the query activity:

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.`

Here's the SQL. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, 
EmailAddress, 
[First Name], 
[Last Name], 
[CAT-Newsletter], 
[CAT-Legislative Update] AS Legislative_and_Regulatory_Updates__c,
ModifiedDate, 
[CAT-Webinars], 
[CAT-Product Service] AS Products_and_Services_Update__c, 
[CAT-Research] AS Research_Insights_and_News__c

CASE WHEN [CAT-Newletter] = 'False' AND 
[CAT-Webinars] = 'False' AND 
Legislative_and_Regulatory_Updates__c = 'False' AND Products_and_Services_Update__c = 'False' AND Research_Insights_and_News__c = 'False' 
THEN 'False'
ELSE 'True' 
END AS Investment_Insights_Market_Commentary__c

FROM [Master Sponsors List]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a comma before the CASE statement.  Here's how I'd format it:

```sql
SELECT 
  SubscriberKey
, EmailAddress
, [First Name]
, [Last Name]
, [CAT-Newsletter]
, [CAT-Legislative Update] Legislative_and_Regulatory_Updates__c
, ModifiedDate
, [CAT-Webinars]
, [CAT-Product Service] Products_and_Services_Update__c
, [CAT-Research] Research_Insights_and_News__c
, CASE 
    WHEN [CAT-Newletter] = 0 
         AND [CAT-Webinars] = 0 
         AND Legislative_and_Regulatory_Updates__c = 0 
         AND Products_and_Services_Update__c = 0 
         AND Research_Insights_and_News__c = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 
  END Investment_Insights_Market_Commentary__c
FROM [Master Sponsors List]
```

Boolean values are *bits* and can be represented with `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.  No need to treat them as strings.

Comment: That was the ticket! A few things had to be changed but that damn comma was it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

That’s not valid syntax for Salesforce SOQL.
Valid syntax is detailed here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm

Comment: I think Chris has a question about Marketing Cloud, therefore question is not about salesforce SOQL, but about query (SQL) in Marketing Cloud Activity step